# "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key" for infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks

I've implemented infinite scroll in React app, however, I get `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key <...>. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. <...>`.

If I replace key={movie.id} by key={i}, infinite scroll stops working.

This is the code of my component:

```
import{ useContext, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card, Grid, CardActionArea, CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
import { MoviesContext } from "../../services/context";
import { Movie } from "../../services/movies.service";
import '../../App.scss';
import './Catalog.scss';
import noImage from '../../images/no-image-available.png';
import loadingSpinner from '../../images/loading-spinner.gif';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import useIntersectionObserver from '../../services/useIntersectionObserver';
import { fetchMovies } from "../../services/movies.service";

const posterBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";

const CatalogCards = () =>  {
  const { movies, updateMovies, searchedMovie, moviesPage, setMoviesPage, setSelectedMovie, setIsMoviePageFirstTimeOpened } = useContext(MoviesContext);
  const loadingRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const entry = useIntersectionObserver(loadingRef, {})
  const isVisible = !!entry?.isIntersecting;

  const SetSelectedMovieId = (id: number) => {
    setIsMoviePageFirstTimeOpened(true);
    setSelectedMovie(id);
  }

  useEffect (
    () => {
      if ( isVisible ) {
        setMoviesPage(moviesPage+1);

        fetchMovies(String(moviesPage))
          .then(nextPage => {
            updateMovies((movies: Movie[]) => movies.concat(nextPage));
          })
          .catch(() => updateMovies([]))
      }
    },
    [isVisible]
  );

  return (
    <div >
      <Grid container spacing={1} className="container-content">
        { 
        movies.length > 0 
          ? 
          movies.map((movie, i) => (
            <Grid item key={movie.id}>
              <NavLink to={'/movie/' + movie.id}>
                <Card className="card-list" onClick={() => SetSelectedMovieId(movie.id)} >
                  <CardActionArea>
                    <CardMedia
                      component="img"
                      alt={"Poster of " + movie.title}
                      image={movie.poster_path ? posterBaseUrl + movie.poster_path : noImage}
                      title={movie.title}
                    />
                  </CardActionArea>
                </Card>
              </NavLink>
            </Grid>
          ))
          :
            searchedMovie ?
            <div className="">Try a different phrase...</div>
            :
            <CardMedia
            component="img"
            image={loadingSpinner}
            className="loading-spinner"
          />
        }
      </Grid>
      <div ref={loadingRef}>...</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CatalogCards;
```

`fetchMovies()` method fetches info about movies from an API.
`useIntersectionObserver` is a custom hook that helps to check if `ref={loadingRef}` appears in the screen and more movies should be fetched.

How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: try this patch `${movie.id}${i}`

Comment: It doesn't work - the warning is not shown anymore but the infinite scroll stops working too

Comment: Please create codesandbox link of your problem